# What happens if I don't declare all functions in header?

Tags: c, header

I'm currently practicing a unit test with GTest, and noticed that I didn't declare all functions written on the target source code (target.c) to its header (target.h). Since I didn't do the test for those undeclared functions, I couldn't notice until now.

Now, it seems that those header-undeclared functions work as 'private' functions since they are not callable from the test code (which includes header of the target source code).

Can I consider this as a way to declare a private function or should I be aware of something else for safety?

Comment: If the functions are to be used outside the source file defining them, they should be declared in a header and the header should be used where the functions are used, and also where they are defined — this ensures consistency. If the functions are not used outside the source file defining them, they should be declared `static`. You should have compilation options set up so that if a function is not declared before it is used, you get a compilation error. Likewise, if you define a non-`static` function before it is declared, you should get a compilation error. Anything else sets you up to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. that does not make your function private. It just then requires the caller to extern that function themselves. Using the static key word is the appropriate way to create a private function. Eg:

```
static void myfunc ()
{
 ...
}
```

Not including it in the header doesn't make it a private function, since any other C file could add an `extern void myfunc()` in either their header or C code and gain access to that function. At compile time, all of that is going to be linked (assuming you are compiling all the files).

BUT all static objects will only have module level (or file scope) visibility

The same goes for variables you only want in the filescope.

Comment: But you should never write an `extern` function declaration in a source file; they should only appear in headers.  Anything else is a maintenance nightmare.